# How to escape double colon in Python Sphinx

Tags: python, escaping, python-sphinx

Let's imagine we have the following FireBreath call:

```
.. method:: Foo::Bar(std::vector)
```

As you may already understood the double colons interfere with the official Sphinx syntax and although it does show up, there is no link, associated with this method (i.e. it couldn't be accessed with `:method:` reference for example).

Adding escape symbol (`\`) didn't really help and although it still shows up, the link doesn't work. Is there any workaround or this is a unavoidable limitation of Sphinx platform?

Comment: Have you tried to use `.. cpp:function:: Foo::Bar(std::vector)`? See http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#id2.

Comment: Could you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [C++ domain](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#id2.) in Sphinx. Like this:

```
.. cpp:function:: Foo::Bar(std::vector)
```

A cross-reference to this method would look like this:

```
:cpp:func:`Foo::Bar`
```